# Positioning issue in chrome with fixed positioned flexslider and sticky navigation

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-position, flexslider

I have a web page with fixed positioned flexslider. I use following code to make flexslider fixed position and to add the slider as the background.

```
.flexslider {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    border: none;
 }
```

and the webpage has a sticky navigation which becomes fixed positioned when the user scroll  to top height of half of the  the viewport height. I did this by using following jQuery and CSS:

jQuery:

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).height()/2;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop) {
        $('.main-header').removeClass('main-header ').addClass('fixed-header');

    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop) {
        $('.fixed-header').removeClass('fixed-header').addClass('main-header ');
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

and my html markup is:

```
   <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="images/image1.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/image2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/image3.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


   <header class="main-header">
                        <h1>heading</h1>
                        <p>
                            paragraph
                        </p>
                        <nav class="site-navigation">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="#slide1">home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#slide2">about</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#slide3">services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#slide4">contact</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#slide5">elements</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>
```

The issue is the navigation does not become fixed and it goes up when it scroll in chrome. If I change the fixed position of flexslider it works fine. This code work perfectly in all the major browsers except Chrome.

How to fix this issue and Is there another way to design a sticky navigation?

Comment: Please excuse my bad english :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for my question. If someone facing the same issue as me you can fix this by removing the styling rule

```
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
```

of flexslider.css.

you can find the answer by visiting here https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/179

Comment: Man thank you so much. You help me solve a big issue I had. In my case had to add this style but you gave me the idea where to look