# Flexslider caption over slider don't animate (only chrome)

Tags: css, flexslider

I am using flexslider to make my home page slider.

I have a problem with the captions. When I change the slides, the caption of every slide appears after the slide is stopped and not during the change from one slide to another.

My css code :

```
.front-page-slider{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 28px;
}

.flexslider ul.slides > li{
position: relative;
}


.flex-caption{
position:absolute;
width: 235px;
height: 445px;
z-index: 50;
top: 25px;
right: 25px;
background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
```

the html

```
<div class="container front-page-slider">
<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <ul class="slides" style="width: 1800%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-900px, 0, 0);">
            <li class="clone" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 900px; float: left; display: block;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://localhost/artech/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/radio-nippon-project.png" class="attachment-front-slider wp-post-image" alt="radio-nippon-project" draggable="false"></a>
                <div class="flex-caption"><h1>Radio Rippon</h1></div>
            </li>
                           /* More <li> with slides etc*/
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js code

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlsContainer: ".front-page-slider",
      controlNav: false,
      slideshow: false
});
```

Also when I am using this

```
top: 25px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Is working fine only for the right direction (when I press the next arrow)

I tried also a variety of combinations with top, left, right, bottom with no luck.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

P.S : I am using only the jquery.flexslider-min.js (Flexslider 2) and not the provided css.

**UPDATE 1** : I noticed that is only happening at chrome (latest version) and not firefox (latet version). Even not at IE10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally I manage to solve it. I had to put : `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to make it work.

Inspired by this answer :

[Positioning issue in chrome with fixed positioned flexslider and sticky navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768540/positioning-issue-in-chrome-with-fixed-positioned-flexslider-and-sticky-navigati?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

useCSS: false,

to slider initialization solved the problem for me.